# Array with Apache Thrift using server Java & Javascript Client

Tags: javascript, java, apache, thrift

im using Javascript to show info generated in Java.
Im talking of 10,000 datas, all of them generated in Java and for porpouse of testing im using random values. Well i want to see this 10,000 values in my javascript page.

I already have a simple Server Java and a Client Javascript to share 2 doubles.

**This is the Thrift file for 2 doubles:**

```
namespace java test_thrift
service test{
    double number(1:double n1, 2:double n2)
}
```

**This is the code of my Javascript Client**

```
function calc() {
var transport = new Thrift.Transport("/service");
var protocol  = new Thrift.Protocol(transport);
var client    = new testClient(protocol);

var workbench = Math.random()*1000;
    try {
      result = client.number(workbench);
      $('#result').val(result);
      $('#result').css('color', 'black');
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    } catch(ouch){
      $('#result').val(ouch.why);
      $('#result').css('color', 'red');
    }
}
```

Im sending a Random only to get the range of the return. Example: 1 return a value from 3 to 9, 2 return a 9 to 15 value, etc.

**And in java i have a testHandler class:**

```
public double number(double n1, double n2) throws TException {
    //System.out.println(n1 + " - " + n2);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    n1 = rnd.nextDouble() * 10 + 1;
    n2 = rnd.nextDouble() * 15 + 10;
    return n2;
}
```

Well this returns 1 value. And i want to see all in my Javascript Page. But with 10,000 elements. How can i do this?

Also i want to add that the final struct to share is like this:

```
 dis[10000][3]={
     ABC,12.5,13.5,
     ACD,14.4,11.5,
     .....ETC......}
```

Im stuck

**Found this, but i dont know how to get it work :/**

```
namespace java test_thrift

typedef list<double> Vector

struct test
{
    1:i32 rows,
    2:i32 cols,
    3:list<Vector> data,
}
```

Comment: Given I understand the problem right: What about using a `list<pair>` with `pair` being a `struct pair { 1: double one, 2: double two }`? This way you can pass as much data as you want with one call. If chaning the server IDL is not a valid choice, then you have to perform 10000 calls (which will be less performant)

Comment: Exactly i want to make just 1 call and pass all the info. But i dont know how  "list<pair>" works. I've never used it. Do you know some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i managed to fix it. Here's a Client JavasCript that make a reequest and a Java server Give back a 10000 x 18 Matrix.

Thrift file:

namespace java test_thrift

```
struct Cell {
  1: string did
  2: double l_x
  3: double l_y
  4: double l_z
  5: double m_x
  6: double m_y
  7: double m_z
  8: double a_x
  9: double a_y
  10: double a_z
  11: double g_x
  12: double g_y
  13: double g_z
  14: string d_t
  15: double tp
  16: double r_q
  17: string o_m
  18: double b_v
}

service test{
    list<Cell>  number( 1 : i16 req)
}
```

Then in Javascript i send only the request:

```
function calc() {
var transport = new Thrift.Transport("/service");
var protocol  = new Thrift.Protocol(transport);
var client    = new pruebaClient(protocol);


var workbench = Math.random()*1000;
var div = document.getElementById('deltat');


    try {

      result = client.number(1);
      div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '\nReady';

    } catch(ouch){

      $('#result').val("ERROR");
      $('#result').css('color', 'red');
    }
}
```

And in result y have the [10000][18] answer and print it like this:

```
for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      //div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '\n' + result[i];
      div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '\n'+result[i].did+' '+result[i].l_x+' '+result[i].l_y+' '+result[i].l_z+' '+result[i].m_x+' '+result[i].m_y+' '+result[i].m_z+' '+result[i].a_x+' '+result[i].a_y+' '+result[i].a_z+' '+result[i].g_x+' '+result[i].g_y+' '+result[i].g_z+' '+result[i].d_t+' '+result[i].tp+' '+result[i].r_q+' '+result[i].o_m+' '+result[i].b_v);
    };
  }
```

Finally the handler in my Java Server is like this:

```
public class TestHandler implements test.Iface {
  public Random rnd = new Random();
  public static List<Cell> p = new ArrayList<Cell>();

  public void test() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        Cell a = new Cell();
        a.did = "SomeString";
        a.l_x = rnd.nextDouble()*10+1;
        a.l_y = rnd.nextDouble()*10+1;
        a.l_z = 0.0;
        a.m_x = 0.0;
        a.m_y = 0.0;
        a.m_z = 0.0;
        a.a_x = 0.0;
        a.a_y = 0.0;
        a.a_z = 0.0;
        a.g_x = 0.0;
        a.g_y = 0.0;
        a.g_z = 0.0;
        a.d_t = "String here";
        a.tp = 0.0;
        a.r_q = 0.0;
        a.o_m = "A";
        a.b_v = 0.0;
        p.add(a);
    }
}
@Override
public List<Cell> number(short req) throws TException {
    test();
    return ips.ReminderBeep.list_d;
}
```

I hope this will be useful for someone

Comment: You are aware of the fact that your answer does not even closely match your own question?

Comment: Why not? I said at the beginning that i will sen a Matrix like this form:
'dis[10000][3]'. Don't you read that?. I just Change the "3" for "18". Whats the matter?. You answer send the data from Javascript to Java and i mentioned that i want the opposite of that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this IDL file

```
namespace java test_thrift

struct MyPair { 
     1: double one
     2: double two 
}

service test{
    list<double>  number( 1 : list<MyPair> data)
}
```

The function is then called like so:

```
var list = [];
for( var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    list.push({
      one : Math.random()*1000,
      two : Math.random()*1000 
    });
}
result = client.number(list);
```

Result should then be your list of returned values, given of course the server end is implemented accordingly.

Comment: It's ok if i reuse the server and just change the handler?. I tried to just print the size of the list but i cant. Javascript's file always go to the catch. Sorry to be this annoying, i'm new in thrift but really appreciate your help.